# How to manually test queries in the rails console with non-model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is my question:
There is a movie_buff folder created for varies method to generate queries and they are not working under any Class. I've tried something like Actor.first.vanity_projects or Movie.first.vanity_projects to test those method, but they all give me like undefined method `vanity_projects' for #. 
Here is what I wrote for the method:

```
def vanity_projects
 Movie
  .select("movies.id, movies.title, actors.name")
  .joins(:actors)
  .where("actors.id = director_id")
  .where("castings.ord = 1")
end
```

[Screenshot for directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WQ1P.png)

How am I be able to test those method in console?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant code instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of result this vanity_project method has to return doesn't seem to be of an object method. Try defining it like a class method, with a self inside one of the Movie or Actor class (or both if you wish, but not recommended). Like this:

```
class Movie
  def self.vanity_projects
    #The Query
  end
end
```

And call this from the console like this:

```
Movie.vanity_projects #=> Returns your query's result.
```